# Flutter DateTime.now is showing wrong time on real device

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, time, flutter-layout

I am showing `DateTime.now();` on the time picker in my app but its showing me wrong time. I have printed out timezone it shows CET but when I put .toLocal it shown the correct device time but .toLocal isnt working with put on `DateTime.now().toLocal(),` like this it still gives wrong time like 23 : 39 even when current time is 00: 20. What I am looking forward to is I want the correct local time/device time to be tracked by the app because I don't the user to select past time. Point to be noted I want the time in 24h standard and if to be specific what timezone I want so that is GMT+1

Here's my code so far for this functionality.

```
TimePickerSpinner(
                      is24HourMode: true,
                      isForce2Digits: true,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      normalTextStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      highlightedTextStyle:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                      time: DateTime.now(),
                      onTimeChange: (time) {
                        DateFormat formatHour = DateFormat("HH");
                        String nowTimeHour = formatHour.format(DateTime.now());
                        String selectedTimeHour = formatHour.format(time);
                        DateFormat formatMints = DateFormat("mm");
                        String nowTimeMints =
                            formatMints.format(DateTime.now());
                        String selectedTimeMints = formatMints.format(time);
                        print(int.parse(nowTimeHour));
                        print(int.parse(selectedTimeHour));
                        if (int.parse(nowTimeHour) >
                            int.parse(selectedTimeHour)) {
                          setState(() {
                            isTimeCorrent = true;
                          });
                        } else if (int.parse(nowTimeHour) ==
                                int.parse(selectedTimeHour) &&
                            int.parse(nowTimeMints) >
                                int.parse(selectedTimeMints)) {
                          setState(() {
                            isTimeCorrent = true;
                          });
                        } else {
                          setState(() {
                            dateTimeSelected = time;
                            isTimeCorrent = false;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
  var date = DateTime.now().toUtc();
```

This will give universal time .so adding or subtracting gmt time get you time.(here `Gmt+1` so add 1 hour to the utc time get the correct time)

[image]

```
  var date = DateTime.now().toUtc().add(Duration(hours:1));
```

here add  Hours 1 => `Gmt +1` represent utc time + hours

Answer (score 0):

In your emulator go to Settings (like you would do in a physical device)
[image]

Then to System -> Date&Time -> and disable "Set time automatically" -> Now you can set the date manually.